# Slicing a sparse array represented by a Dictionary<Tuple<int, int, int>, double> without enumerating all the keys: is that possible?

Tags: c#, dictionary, sparse-matrix

I am representing a 3D array as a sparse matrix, with keys being `Tuple<int, int, int>`, where each value in the tuple is one of `i, j, k` matrix indices.

Now I would like to get a slice of it. For example, I want all the values where `Key.Item1` has a given index.

Is it possible to get these values without iterating over all dictionary keys?

As a bonus, is there another data structure (besides dictionary) to represent multidimensional sparse arrays in C# so that these slice operations are more straightforward?

Comment: Something like this :             Dictionary<Tuple<int, int, int>, Double> dict = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int, int>, double>();
            var results = dict.Keys.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Item1 == 123).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng the intention is exactely that, but I am asking exactely if there is a better way than enumeration to achieve the same result.

Comment: @heltonbiker probably not with dis data structure. maybe you actually want a Tuple of three dictionaries keyed on your i, j, k with list of value references as values? this way if you want all values with j = 5 you just go to Tuple.Item2[5] ?

Comment: You could keep 3 lookup dictionaries based on each dimension that maps to a list of tuple keys.  But then you have maintain them on addition and deletion of an item.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

If you truly want a dictionary, then use an ordered dictionary. Define the order as a simple calculation like `Item1*1000000+Item2*1000+Item3`. The magnitudes allow you to do some modulo math to traverse along the dimension you want (I picked the factors arbitrarily because I don't know the size of your universe).

To get all the **Item2** elements, you would do a binary search where "found" means the first calculated value that contains **Item2**. From there you walk forward *and* backwards until you have elements that no longer contain **Item2**. That's your result set. You do the same thing with the other items in your tuple.

Beyond the dictionary a reversible **[trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)** of ints, and a list for **Item2** could get you what you want. A search for a single tuple means starting at the top of the trie and walking down; for **Item3**, start at the bottom and walk up. For **Item2**'s, start with the target **Item2** value in the second list and do one lookup each for the other items.

The algorithm for finding all of one dimension of your tuple is the same as above, but the next level visits all of the items rather than looking up one.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better structure for this, but you could use a `List<Tuple<int, int, int, double>>` instead of a dictionary and sort it by the dimension you will be slicing in. Then you can binary search to find the slice you want. Of course this only works if you are always slicing by the same dimension.

Comment: Interesting, but where would I store the values? And what about removing and inserting?

Comment: Oops.. I added a double to the list. If you need to access a single item you will  have to make 3 binary searches. I would wrap this in a class though.